# How to set a calculated default value for a drop down list field in Sharepoint

Tags: infopath

I need help with the drop down list box. Let me try to explain to you what I am trying to achieve.
I have a Assigned To field(Person/Group picker With Multiple Selection) and Group User field(drop down box) in a SharePoint List/ InfoPath form.
For Drop down box the choice data is being pulled from Assigned to. This Dropdown Box is Hidden unless until multiple users are selected in assigned to field

I would like to be able to assign a ticket to multiple users or to a single user. If it's multiple users then group user can be assigned by selecting one of the member in that group.

But if the Assigned To is a Single User, Then by default I want to set the user in Group user. This is where I have problem, I tried using rules and workflow, but it doesn't work. it shows as a choice 
See Image http://screencast.com/t/Wdx2izyiPI

I need your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It looks you have to add content editor webpart in your newform.aspx (hope on list item creation) to add a reference to the JQuery file. On providing a single value in people picker, dropdown will be populated with single value, then you can select this value using JQuery and further more if you want, can disable the dropdown too.

Comment: Please don't use chat speak like "u" and "ur".

Comment: What jQuery file? Your answer does not make sense at all.

Comment: Please write all your required scripts in a text file (or JS file) and upload it in a document library. Then add the reference in content editor webpart. It will work.